Как настроить эмулятор в Android Studio, что бы не лагал?
Скачал Android Studio, запускаю эумулятор там примерно минуты 3-4 GRADLE PROJECT IN PROGRESS. Далее появляются некоторые ошибки The system UI isn't responding. Если нужно что-то скинуть напишите скину, может у меня настройки какие-то неправильные.

В биосе компа включи vt-x/vt-d/amd-v . Используй образ эмулятора с архитектурой x86 x64. Включи аппаратное ускорение в эмуляторе.
